# Are Too Character Based and Too Plot Based the same?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

It's been [proposed](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3229/risk-factor-definition-too-individual-character-based#comment8772_3229) that the risk factors "Too Character Based" and "Too Plot Based" could be merged together into one close reason and that there is enough overlap between them to warrant that.

I can certainly think of question that are both plot and character, but equally I can think of questions that are just plot and questions that are just character.

What do people think?

Answer (score 4):

Multi-faceted close reasons are fine, especially when we only get a few, so long as there's a unifying theme.  A question doesn't have to be asking about plot *and* characters to be closed as **story-based**.  In both cases the remedy is the same: instead of asking about stuff happening *in* your world, ask about *your world*.

Not only could these factors be collapsed into a single reason, but I feel that the reason would be stronger for it.  Story versus world -- we can explain that.  Character-based when *groups* of characters can be ok and *significant world-affecting characters* can be ok gets confusing.  Let's move it up a level.

[More background and some language](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3254/28).

Comment: I like the proposal, including the name "story based".

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it, plot-based would be about plot events, some of which would be informed by character design. Character-based questions, on the other hand, would be specifically about character-building, some of which would be informed by plot.

For instance, plot building: "How would these characters kill a bunch of bearded aliens?"

And character building: "How would this bearded guy feel about killing bearded aliens?"

Both of these are off-topic, so we should have a reason for that, but I don't think we need both character-based *and* plot-based. If I had to choose, I'd say character-based *could* cover both cases, but I'd much rather come up with a better name to blanket both more definitively. No suggestions though.

Comment: We could just call it "too plot or character based" :) Can we think of any examples which are clearly one but not the other? I'm struggling to come up with good ones which suggests they are linked.

Comment: The high school misfits IN SPACE has successfully poisoned the beard grooming products of the bearded aliens, destroying them. There was much rejoicing on Earth, but this one bearded guy offered a different perspective. "They where not too different from us. They had hopes and dreams just like we do. Beard related dreams."