# Opening a direct link with an anchor breaks the layout

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I just klicked on a notification of a comment in my inbox. I therefore found that loading a comment via direct link ([like this](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3547/educating-new-users-about-our-scope/3550?noredirect=1#comment9636_3550)) breaks the site and the content is moved so that the comment appears in the top left corner of the window.

I could reprodue this on *IE11 11.0.9600.18204 (Windows 7)* - but not on *Safari 9.1 11601.5.17.1 (MacOS X El Capitan)* so this seems to be an IE problem?

This is how it looks like:
[image: image of broken design]

This also happens when clicking on the *answered x hours ago* link in the overview. My best guess would be that this happens everytime an anchor is used. Clicking on a *asked x hours ago* message works fine.

Comment: Can reproduce with IE 11.306.10586.0 on Win10 Fullscreen & Windowed - but it works perfectly fine with Edge

Comment: We're investigating.

Comment: I believe that we've fixed this. Can you confirm that it's no longer an issue?

Comment: @KurtisBeavers yup, it's fixed. Thank you! Would you explain the problem? I am curious :)

Comment: @T3H40 We had some image layering in the header to eventually create an effect of the stars moving, but it was interfering with some scroll-to-comment javascript , so I removed the layering witch allowed us to simplify the header images.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Too bad. I hope you did not drop this idea entirely, that would be an awesome feature!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kurtis Beavers told in the comments,

> we've fixed this.

for those interested in the reason:

> [they] had some image layering in the header to eventually create an effect of the stars moving, but it was interfering with some scroll-to-comment javascript , so [they] removed the layering witch allowed us to simplify the header images.

<sub><sub>This question needed an answer to be accepted to not be pushed eventually by the Community</sub></sub>