# Sharing the "how-to" meta content via help

Tags: discussion, feature-request, help-center

Is there a way to have the links to the, Risk Factors, Perfect Question etc meta posts show up under help?

If yes (it's yes, thank you Monica)

I would like to propose we add the following questions to the help center:

[How to write the perfect question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3624/how-to-write-the-perfect-question?cb=1)

and

[Worldbuilding Scope - Risk Factors](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3206/worldbuilding-scope-risk-factors)

Vote your agreement or disdain :)

Answer (score 5):

Moderators can edit the [on-topic page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.  Please propose a specific addition on meta so people can vote.  Thanks.

The tour is largely not editable.  (I think we can edit the first paragraph, but that's not the place to put this info.)

Comment: I would agree that Risk Factors would make more sense for the on-topic page.  But I don't know that "How to write the perfect question?" belongs there.  It might actually fit in the first paragraph of the tour.

Comment: @Brythan the "risk factors" post strikes me as a poor fit for a link from the tour or help center.  The question is inward-facing (let's collect stuff, here's why, use this format...), while the "perfect question" post is outward-facing (read this before asking).  Individual risk factors can and should be linked in appropriate places (like custom close reasons), but I'm hesitant to send newcomers to that whole meta post.  It's long and potentially overwhelming.

Comment: You might want to suggest that @James split off those questions from this post then.  As is, people seem to be voting to add both of them to the on-topic page.  As a side issue, perhaps we need an outward facing version of Risk Factors, as people are already directing newcomers there ("I voted to close your post, here's three meta posts that cover why"; Risk Factors is one of the three).  I can flag those comments for moderator attention if they are confusing people.

Comment: I upvoted the question because I think we should do something here, though I don't think we should link to both in their current forms.  I'm hoping that people will offer answers with specific proposals, so people can vote on those.

Answer (score 3):

We should link to [How to write the perfect question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3624/how-to-write-the-perfect-question) from the [on-topic help page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), in the paragraph after the lists of what is on- and off-topic.  That paragraph currently reads:

> Note that questions must be [specific](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [answerable](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). If you are looking for discussion, brainstorming, or an overall process rather than specific question-and-answers, the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange might not be a good place for your question. Such questions may however be welcome in [Worldbuilding Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=worldbuilding.stackexchange.com). Also see [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) for why this type of question is hard, and some guidelines on how to post good subjective questions which are less likely to end up being closed.

If we could edit [how to ask a good question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) I'd also link it in there, but that page isn't currently editable by moderators.  (I've [asked on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280428/162102) if we can change that.)

I don't think the risk-factors post in its current form is a good candidate for linking in the help center.  It's long and the question (itself long) is more "inward-facing" (addressed to the community).  I'd worry that a new user would stop reading before getting to the important stuff.  People can and should link to *specific risk factors* (answers) when appropriate, and the content of that page fed into the perfect-question list, so I think we'll be covered if we make the changes I've proposed.

Comment: I would like the ? removed from How to write the perfect question (Or change it to actually be a question such as starting it with "How do I" instead of "How to". Other than that I agree.

Comment: @TimB done (but the link text here doesn't automatically update).